# Principal ideal domain , diagonal form

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

I'm trying to find the diagonal form using row and column operation over $\mathbb Z$ of the following matrix :

$$ L =
\begin{pmatrix}
 0&0  &1 \\ 
 0&1  &-7 \\ 
 1&0  &-7 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
 14&14  &26 \\ 
 14&18  &26 \\ 
 2&2  &2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ LA = B =\begin{pmatrix}
 0&0  &1 \\ 
 0&1  &-7 \\ 
 1&0  &-7 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 14&14  &26 \\ 
 14&18  &26 \\ 
 2&2  &2 
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 2&2  &2 \\ 
 0&4  &12 \\ 
 0&0  &12 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now we expect three matrices on the right. First we need
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 2&2  &2 \\ 
 0&4  &12 \\ 
 0&0  &12 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&t  &0 \\ 
 0&1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 2&2t+2  &2 \\ 
 0&4  &12 \\ 
 0&0  &12 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 2&2  &2 \\ 
 0&4  &12 \\ 
 0&0  &12 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1  &0 \\ 
 0&1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 2& 0 &2 \\ 
 0&4  &12 \\ 
 0&0  &12 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 2&0  &2 \\ 
 0&4  &12 \\ 
 0&0  &12 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&0  &0 \\ 
 0&1  &-3 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 2& 0 &0 \\ 
 0&4  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &12 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ R = R_1 R_2 R_3 =
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1  &0 \\ 
 0&1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&0  &-1 \\ 
 0&1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&0  &0 \\ 
 0&1  &-3 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 1& -1 &2 \\ 
 0&1  &-3 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ LA = B =\begin{pmatrix}
 0&0  &1 \\ 
 0&1  &-7 \\ 
 1&0  &-7 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 14&14  &26 \\ 
 14&18  &26 \\ 
 2&2  &2 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1& -1 &2 \\ 
 0&1  &-3 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 2&0  &0 \\ 
 0&4  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &12 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But I'm not sure if the answer is correct can anyone help me with it ? It would be really welcomed

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117563/discussion-on-question-by-jguyvm-principal-ideal-domain-diagonal-form).